# Where to find the 5 or 10 year returns for a mutual fund?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, rate-of-return, yahoo-finance, research

I’m researching some mutual funds and am trying to find the 5 or 10 year return. However, all I can find is the YTD return.

For example, Yahoo Finance shows the Yacktman Focused Svc (YAFFX) has an 8.33% YTD return, but when I click [the “5y” link](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=YAFFX%20Interactive#symbol=YAFFX;range=5y), the page still says 8.33 YTD.

How can I find the 5 or 10 year return?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yahoo's primary business isn't providing mutual fund performance data.  They aim to be convenient, but often leave something to be desired in terms of completeness.

Try [Morningstar](http://www.morningstar.com) instead.  Their mission is investment research.

Here's [a link to Morningstar's data for the fund you specified](http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/f?region=USA&ss=gf&t=YAFFX).  If you scroll down, you'll see:

[image: Morningstar sample mutual fund performance data]

Comment: Thank you. Just so I'm clear, it's 5y is 14.86% and 10y is 11.17%, correct?

Comment: Yes, the *"Fund"* line is the fund's CAGR over the period shown in the column headers.  Quick check: $10,000 * (1.1486^5) = $19,991.43 .. which is almost the $19,993 in the line above. (Some precision beyond the two decimal places likely accounts for the difference.)

Comment: doing the calculation the other way 19,993 = 10,000*R^5 or ln-1(ln(1.9993)/5) = 1.1486179